# HttpResponseMessage with Unauthorize status code and Content // response without required WWW-Authenticate header field

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Using ASP.NET Web API 2, if I want to return HttpResponseMessage with Unauthorized status code, I'll get different response headers - with or without WWW-Authenticate header field - depending on whether this response message has content or not.

WWW-Authenticate header field is a required field for Unauthorized response according to [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

And the lack of WWW-Authenticate header field in the response causes an error for the next request.

To see the problem you can create a new Web API project and to add a simple test controller:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            // Content = new StringContent("You are not authorized"),
        };

        return responseMessage;
    }
}
```

If the response message doesn't have a content we'll get normal 401 responses for our calls:
[image]

With responses:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVjdHNcVGVzdEFwaVxUZXN0QXBpXGFwaVxUZXN0?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 01 May 2015 05:31:20 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

If we add content to the response message (uncomment the content line), each second response will be not 401, but 500

[image]

The responses with 401 will have the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 22
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVjdHNcVGVzdEFwaVxUZXN0QXBpXGFwaVxUZXN0?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 01 May 2015 05:34:38 GMT

You are not authorized
```

And the responses with 500 will say

```
Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
Description: an unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and  where it originated in the code..... Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
```

So it looks like it happens because previous responses are illegal - they don't contain WWW-Authenticate header attribute.

But it doesn't help even if I try to add WWW-Authenticate manually

```
public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("You are not authorized"),
            };

            responseMessage.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Bearer");

            return responseMessage;
        }
    }
```

Now it's in the response

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 22
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVjdHNcVGVzdEFwaVxUZXN0QXBpXGFwaVxUZXN0?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 01 May 2015 05:43:51 GMT

You are not authorized
```

but I still have every second request 500 instead of 401.

Can anyone clarify what's going on here and how to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

The `Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.` error message from the response with 500 is caused by a module trying to write http headers into the response stream once your action has executed - since your action has already written both the headers and the body.

The *usual* culprits are **FormsAuthentication** and **Owin cookie authentication** kicking in and trying to replace 401 with 302 (redirect to login page).

**Scenario:**
1. your action executed - added header `401 Unauthorized` to the headers collection plus wrote the header into the response stream and then wrote the body (*You are not authorized*) to the response stream.
2. FormsAuthenticationModule sees `401 Unauthorized` header in the response headers collection and attempts to change that to `302 Redirect to login page`, plus attempts to write the corresponding header to the response stream - which fails with `Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.`, since the headers were already written earlier.

**Possible fixes:**

1) if **FormsAuthenticationModule** is in your request pipeline

- consider disabling it if you are not using it
- in .net 4.5 you you can suppress forms authentication redirection by setting [HttpResponse.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.suppressformsauthenticationredirect.aspx) property to *false*
- if not on .net 4.5, consider using HttpModule which will suppress this redirection

[Phil Haack blogged on all the above options](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx/).

2) if using **OWIN** cookie authentication - consider [not setting LoginPath property](http://forums.asp.net/t/1994216.aspx?Server%20cannot%20set%20status%20after%20HTTP%20headers%20have%20been%20sent#5761736)

Comment: thanks. but I use neither FormsAuthentication, nor Owin authentication. and I can't see how it may be related to Content of HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: @DmitryKhryukin I have added more details on how they may be related, please take a look.

Comment: btw, just to be on the same page - by 'using FormsAuthentication' I actually meant having the `FormsAuthenticationModule` in the request pipeline - updated the answer.